# IIS Directory Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dns

I am trying to get the website id from IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2. I want to fetch the Id, then add a website pointer for the website in IIS. I'm not sure where to grant the permissions for the code to work and at the same time, not leaving my web server vulnerable.

Here is my code for fetching Id

```
    string result = "-1";

    DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/w3svc", "localhost"));

    foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
    {
        if (site.Properties["ServerComment"] != null)
        {
            if (site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value != null)
            {
                if (string.Compare(site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString(),

                                        "website.com", true) == 0)
                {
                    result = site.Name;
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
```

> **This is the error that is thrown:**
>
> ```
> Access is denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
> current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
> about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Access 
> is denied.
>
>
> Source Error:
> ```
>
> Line 22:         DirectoryEntry w3svc = new 
>       DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/w3svc", serverName));
>       Line 23: 
>       Line 24:         foreach (DirectoryEntry site in w3svc.Children)
>       Line 25:         {
>       Line 26:             if (site.Properties["ServerComment"] != null)
>
> ```
> Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DNS_IIS\DNS.aspx.cs    Line: 24
>
> Stack Trace:
>
>
> [COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied.
> ]
>    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
> +597561
>    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
>    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer() +42
>    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.GetEnumerator() +49
>    DNS.GetWebSiteId(String serverName, String websiteName) in c:\inetpub
>  \wwwroot\DNS_IIS\DNS.aspx.cs:24
>    DNS.btnDNS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot
> \DNS_IIS\DNS.aspx.cs:85
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String 
> eventArgument) +155
>    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
> +3804
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple thing to sort out.

So I just changed the Identity of the ApplicationPool to LocalSystem and it worked 100%.